# Org custom agenda to show today's habits sorted by priority

Tags: org-mode

I use [Berndt's](http://doc.norang.ca/org-mode.html) org-mode config for the most part. However, I would like to modify his habits custom agenda command to show today's habits sorted by priority (actually, what I'd really like is just to have my habits sorted by priority in the main agenda view, but that is for another day as I think it is harder to achieve). The closest I have come so far is: habits with a scheduled date of today (a different concept, not what I want) sorted by priority:

```
("h" "Habits" tags-todo "STYLE=\"habit\"+SCHEDULED=\"<+0d>\""
           ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Habits")
            (org-agenda-sorting-strategy
             '(priority-down time-down todo-state-down
                               effort-up category-keep))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

```
("h" "Habits" tags-todo "STYLE=\"habit\"+SCHEDULED<=\"<today>\""
           ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Habits")
            (org-agenda-sorting-strategy
             '(priority-down time-down todo-state-down
                               effort-up category-keep))))
```

This will probably help someone later. This page helped: http://orgmode.org/manual/Matching-tags-and-properties.html

Update: The above works, but since  is hourless, it is better to use less than, <, `<tomorrow>` if you wish to include habits which may have an hour and minute component for today.

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was:
(set org-agenda-todo-ignore-scheduled 'future)